# No module named/Parent module not loaded in Python 3.5.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this structure for my package:

```
/code_trou
    __init__.py
    Main.py
    Menu.py
    /postprocessing
    /preprocessing
    Mesh.py
    Point.py
    /processing
        FDM.py
    /tools
        dllmrg.py
        errormrg.py
        /__pycache_
           errormrg.cpython-35.pyc
```

When I execute my `Main.py` with:

```
from tools.errormrg import *
```

I have this error: `"No module named 'tools'"`

It's the same when I execute `Point.py` with:

```
from tools.dllmrg import *
```

For `Point.py` I tried [the Intra-package References described in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and it doesn't seem to work: I get the error `"Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import"` when executing `Point.py` with this instead:

```
from ..tools.dllmrg import *
```

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in `/tools`, to make that a module too (same for the other sub-modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What make a directory a Python package is the presence of a `__init__.py` file. There are no such files in your `tools` and  `processing` directory so Python does not recognize them as packages.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages